# Change Host header in nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx

I am running nginx as reverse proxy for the site example.com to loadbalance a ruby application running in backend server. I have the following `proxy_set_header` field in nginx which will pass host headers to backend ruby. This is required by ruby app  to identify the subdomain names.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://rubyapp.com;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```

Now I want to create an alias `beta.example.com`, but the host header passed to backend should still be `www.example.com` otherwise the ruby application will reject the requests. So I want something similar to below inside location directive.

```
if ($http_host = "beta.example.com") {
    proxy_pass http://rubyapp.com;
    proxy_set_header Host www.example.com;
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: This is more appropriate for [sf].

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You cannot use **proxy_pass** in if block, so I suggest to do something like this before setting proxy header:

```
set $my_host $http_host;
if ($http_host = "beta.example.com") {
  set $my_host "www.example.com";
}
```

And now you can just use **proxy_pass** and **proxy_set_header** without if block:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://rubyapp.com;
  proxy_set_header Host $my_host;
}
```

Comment: In what scope should I write the if statement ? server or location ?

Comment: It should be mentioned, that this directive can be used only once for the header on the current level due to [the documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header). 
> `proxy_set_header` Allows redefining or appending fields to the request header passed to the proxied server. ... directives are inherited from the previous configuration level if and only if there are no proxy_set_header directives defined on the current level

Answer (score 35):

[map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) is better than `set` + `if`.

```
map $http_host $served_host {
    default $http_host;
    beta.example.com www.example.com;
}

server {
    [...]

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://rubyapp.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $served_host;
    }
}
```

Comment: In nginx docs, it's mentioned that set and if are fine if not in the location, but within the server. However, map is also a good alternative.

Comment: Could you source the docs you mention? I never read that.

Moreover, tickets for nginx involving `if` often points out trouble related to their use. For instance: [#1383](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1383).

Advice to avoid `set` & `if` still stands.

Answer (score 4):

Just a small tip. Sometimes you may need to use **X-Forwarded-Host** instead of **Host** header. That was my case where Host header worked but only for standard HTTP port 80. If the app was exposed on non-standard port, then this port was lost when the app generated redirects. So finally what worked for me was:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
```

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to solve the same situation, but with `uwsgi_pass`.

After some research, I figured out that, in this scenario, it's required to:

```
uwsgi_param HTTP_HOST $my_host;
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much!